How to invert the direction of a single axis tick in matplotlib?
I'd like to invert the direction of a single axis tick (and its label) along the x-axis to highlight some specified value.
I was successful in manipulating other attributes but apparently inverting the direction of a single tick is not so easily done. Here is my failed attempt at inverting the tick direction. Note that all other attributes apply as expected:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, 10), np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
ax.tick_params(axis="x", direction="out")

ticks = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
ticks[2]._apply_params(direction="in", color="r", width=22)

plt.show()

Desired outcome:


You could use a secondary axis to draw the tick separately.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, 10), np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
ax.tick_params(axis="x", direction="out")

ax.xaxis.set_ticks([0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])

secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('bottom')
secax.set_ticks([0.2])
secax.tick_params(direction='in', pad=-20, labelcolor='red')

plt.show()



Thank you, this did the job quite nicely!

You can set label1 attributes
ticks = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
ticks[2].label1.set_y(0.1)
ticks[2].label1.set_color("r")



This doesn't invert the tick, though

@SiHa this is what direction="in" parameter suppose to do.

@Guy that does solve the tick label issue. From what I understand, the direction="in" is supposed to invert the ticks themselves.

@Biggzlar can you post a picture of the expected results?

@Guy sure thing, I updated the question with the desired result.

@Biggzlar ok, so it is what you were looking for. I'm not that familiar with matplotlib, I'm mot sure why direction="in" didn't work.
